nasm can't parse org 0x7c00 and gives an error
I'm trying to compile an assembly project, but when it gets to this code it just errors:
bits 16

org 0x7c00
global _start

_start:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 'H'
    int 0x10


times 510-($-$$) db 0

dw 0xaa55

Error message:
src/bootloader.asm:3: error: parser: instruction expected
Makefile:
ASM := nasm
LD := ld
QEMU := qemu-system-i386
PROJECT := OS
ASMFLAGS := -f elf
LDFLAGS := -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0x7e00 --oformat binary
SRC_DIR := src
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.asm)
BUILD_DIR := build
OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.asm=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
.PHONY: all build run clean

all: build

build: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECT).bin

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.asm
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECT).bin: $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

run: build
    $(QEMU) $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECT).bin

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

OS: Debian 12 WSL
nasm -version: NASM version 2.16.01
If I comment out the org 0x7c00 line, it compiles perfectly

You used -f elf which does not support org. You are already setting the section address using -Ttext 0x7e00 (which should of course be 7c00 not 7e00) so you don't need the org anyway.
